# Open source wallet code for custom ethereum private token

Tags: wallets, private-blockchain

I have a client who has decided to make a custom token on ethereum, run in a **private setup** - ie. not on the mainnet or any of the testnets.
Is their any open source wallet code available which we can simply use to listen in on our private Blockchain and create/manage accounts like in Mist.

I understand Mist/Ethereum Wallet is itself an option (wherein we connect to our private Blockchain instead), however we are looking for a more simple, bare-bones wallet code which we can use for our custom token alone.

Answer (score 2):

A "wallet" in its minimal form (since you are looking for more bare-bones version) does the following tasks:

- manage private keys and addresses
- format and sign transactions

Therefore it does not matter on which chain you are (or if it is a private chain). You should be able to use, e.g. https://www.myetherwallet.com for your private net and connect to a local node for broadcasting txs instead of using the Ethereum main net. You could also fork MEW and customise it as per your needs.

If you want to go one level lower you could use simple libraries such as [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx). Keep in mind that you then need to track the `nonce` yourself or use some service to obtain the correct `nonce` of the account that you want to sign a tx.